# How to post mapped data to database via api endpoint in react native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am trying to post Mapped data array to database using Fetch API endpoint: https://app.example.pro/add-to-cart, but its not working. It only works when array data is not mapped.

**Mapped Array**

```
const data = cart.map((item) => ({
      VendorName: item.vendorDetails.VendorName,
      totalStock: "70",
      PricePerLiter: item.vendorDetails.PricePerLiter,
      placeName: item.vendorDetails.placeName,
      totalamount: "400",
    }));
```

Unmapped array data - this one works

```
    const data = {
      VendorName: "Pure Milk Farms",
      totalStock: "70",
      PricePerLiter: "47.00",
      placeName: "Nyeri",
      totalamount: "500",
    };
```

fetch handle code

```
console.log(data);
    
    fetch('https://app.example.pro/add-to-cart', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        // Handle success
        console.log('Success:', responseData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
```

I want to use Mapped array to post data, where I am going wrong. Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, you must create a function that contains your 'POST' method.

```js
const createdFunction = (data) => {
// parameter 'data' contains the value of unmapped data

 fetch('https://app.example.pro/add-to-cart', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        // Handle success
        console.log('Success:', responseData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
}
```

After finished, you can call your created function inside your map method like this.

```js
const data = cart.map((item) => {
      //Get MappedData
      const mappedData = {
         VendorName: item.vendorDetails.VendorName,
         totalStock: "70",
         PricePerLiter: item.vendorDetails.PricePerLiter,
         placeName: item.vendorDetails.placeName,
         totalamount: "400",
      }

     //# Call your created function and pass your mapped data
     createdFunction(mappedData);
    });
```

map method loops your array of data, so what happened in there is that you using your createdFunction multiple times by the length of your array data.